# How can I create Jaxb java classes to handle similar elements

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a schema:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="get_item">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="imgpurl1"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="imgurl1"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="imgcap1"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="imgpurl2"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="imgurl2"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="imgcap2"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="imgpurlN"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="imgurlN"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="imgcapN"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The xml for this looks like:

```
<?xml version=“1.0”?>
<get_item>
 .......snip.......
<imgpurl1></imgpurl1>
<imgurl1></imgurl1>
<imgcap1></imgcap1>
…
<imgpurlN></imgpurlN>
<imgurlN></imgurlN>
<imgcapN></imgcapXN>
</get_item>
```

Where there can be any number of elements for imgurl1...N.  I don't know what N can/will be so I'd like to be able to pass that as a parameter and have it created correctly automatically.

Obviously the Eclipse generation from schema does not provide this, so how can I modify the created classes so they'll handle N number of elements?

Is there a way to do a custom jaxb adapter to marshal this the way I need it?

Comment: Did you try with defining N elements under the 'get_item' sequence with maxOccurs="unbounded" so that this would be a Collection in the generated Java class (N is number of growing elements like imgurl, imgcap etc...).

Comment: @Dinakar please tell me more, it sounds promising but I don't understand.  Is this something I'd do to the schema?

Comment: yes, the schema should be updated. Sample is posted as answer. Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with something like this:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"  
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="get_item">
<xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="imgpurl" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="imgurl" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="imgcap" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: This creates multiple <imgurl> and/or <imgcap>. What I need is <imgurl1> and <imgcap1>.  I need it to tack the index number on the end of the element name <imgurl2> <imgurl3> <imgurl4>

Comment: Is there a way to build a custom Adapter to marshal the list with the index tacked onto the end of the element name?

Comment: How about defining another complex type that holds imgpurl, imgurl & imgcap ?

Comment: that won't matter unless I can control what the name of the element is.  I need to be able to tack an integer onto the end of "imgurl" "imgpurl" or "imgcap".